# object and assign a concatenated string from two inputs

Tags: javascript

We have a site that recommend website domain.

That get domains, site names and then create an Object with them.

For example :

**If site names are "google,yahoo" and domain are "com,net,org" as inputs**

Output should be :

```
 google: {com: "google.com", net: "google.net", org: "google.org"}
 yahoo: {com: "yahoo.com", net: "yahoo.net", org: "yahoo.org"}
```

This is really confused me. how can I create above object with given input with new method ?

any solution would be my pleasure

Comment: Two nested .forEach()s will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const sites = "google,yahoo".split(',')
const domains = "com,net,org".split(',')

const output = sites.reduce((res, site) => {
  return {
    ...res,
    [site]: domains.reduce((res, domain) => {
      return {
        ...res,
        [domain]: site + '.' + domain
      }
    }, {})
  }
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const sites = "google,yahoo"; const domains = "com,net,org";
const sitesArray = sites.split(',');
const domainsArray = domains.split(',');
let res = {};
sitesArray .forEach(siteKey => {
    res[siteKey] = {};
    domainsArray.forEach(domain => {
        res[siteKey][domain]= siteKey + "." + domain;
    })
    
})
// test
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

even shorter you can do it using one array.map.

```js
function RecommendDomain(address) {
    let domain = ["com", "org", "net", "me"];
    let keyValue =  domain.map((value) => {
        return [value, address + "." + value];
    });
  return Object.fromEntries(keyValue)
}


let a = RecommendDomain("google");
let b = RecommendDomain("yahoo");
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```